# Displaying the current value of the hive variable

Tags: hive, hiveql

I know, that I can set different parameters in hive using `SET` keyword. For example:

```
SET orc.compress = SNAPPY
```

But how I can display current value of the hive parameter? 
I tried to use `SELECT` clause in several variations. For example:

```
SELECT * From ${orc.compress};
```

But no one of them aren't workig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just give:

```
SET <varibale_name> ;
```

It will display the latest value stored.